# Retrofit2 ApiInterface.getCurrentCurrency(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to learn Retrofit2 with MVVM architecture and I have problems with null:

> retrofit2.Call
>   com.example.daniellachacz.currencyconverter2.data.network.ApiInterface.getCurrentCurrency(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

`ApiInterface`

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("currency")
Call<Currency> getCurrentCurrency(@Query("base") String base,
                                  @Query("target") String target);
}
```

`CurrencyRepository.class`

```
public class CurrencyRepository {

private ApiInterface apiInterface;

public CurrencyRepository(Application application) {

}

public LiveData<Currency> getCurrency(String base, String target) {

    final MutableLiveData<Currency> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    apiInterface.getCurrentCurrency(base, target).enqueue(new Callback<Currency>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Currency> call, Response<Currency> response) {
            data.setValue(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Currency> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    return data;
}

}
```

`MainViewModel.class`

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;
public final ObservableField<String> base = new ObservableField<>();

public MainViewModel(Application application) {
   super(application);
   currencyRepository = new CurrencyRepository(application);
}

public void setBase() {
    String mBase = "EUR";
    String mTarget = "PLN";
    currencyRepository.getCurrency(mBase, mTarget);
    base.set(mBase);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs because you don't initialize `ApiInterface` instance. You need to create your `ApiInterface` via Retrofit:

```
public ApiInterface createApi() {
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(your_api_url)
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson())) // for automatic serialization using Gson
         .build();
    return retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
}
```

You can define it into repository:

```
public class CurrencyRepository {

private ApiInterface apiInterface;

public CurrencyRepository(Application application) {
    apiInterface = createApi();
}

public LiveData<Currency> getCurrency(String base, String target) {

    final MutableLiveData<Currency> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    apiInterface.getCurrentCurrency(base, target).enqueue(new Callback<Currency>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Currency> call, Response<Currency> response) {
            data.setValue(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Currency> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
    return data;
    }
}
```

Or pass through constructor:

```
public CurrencyRepository(ApiInterface apiInterface) {
    this.apiInterface = apiInterface;
}
// then
public MainViewModel(Application application) {
   super(application);
   currencyRepository = new CurrencyRepository(createApi());
}
```

Or pass `ApiInterface` through constructor using DI framework (Dagger2 or Toothpick).

Comment: Yep, you are right! I used first option. Thank you!